# Media queries being ignored in CS Cart

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cs-cart

I've tried to figure out why but nothing seems to be working and all the other questions I've seen relating to 'media queries being ignored' are due to media queries not being set up in the right way or not in the right place. I've looked at the answers and none of them solve this (what seems) unique issue.

So here is my code, I'm using the Custom CSS editor inside CS Cart 4. It uses LESS and Bootstrap 2 built into it's core. Here is what I've written so far. Can you spot any problems?

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
@viewport { width: device-width; }

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

  .nav-menu { margin: 0; } [...]

}
```

I can't provide a link to the site as it's on a local development system but basically there is a menu that I have in the header. Once the screen is below 1200px the menu gets a little squashed down so I want to change it so it looks nicer and degrades gracefully the lower the screen size. Problem is; my complete set of media queries are being ignored.

Any advice? I'm completely stumped with this one.

Comment: Try using `@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {...`

Comment: Thanks, I used that to replace the 1200px line and it semi works. So now it degrades properly for 1200px, but the other media queries below for 979px, 767px and 480px still don't work. I have found that when I remove everything from the Custom CSS theme editor and save it so it's blank, when I then paste in all my CSS again the 1200px works. Why is it doing that?

Comment: Okay so the answer that @vivekkupadhyay gave semi fixed this. I also found that if you delete everything from the editor (as I mentioned above) and save the style. Paste your CSS back into the editor again and save then it'll work fine as expected. Spent hours on this. Hopefully this clears up things for anyone else with the same issue. Sorry to waste anyone's time!

Comment: place your `media-queries` in descending order, and use only those what needed instead of un-necessary usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how it works in CS-Cart in the following file:

design/themes/responsive/css/tygh/responsive.less

Here is the example which will work correctly. No any additional changes are required

```
@media (max-width : 1200px) {
     .nav-menu { margin: 0; }
}
```